# Get a password validation from a table number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a password inut that get value (when the user click on the password input) from a table that display numbers from [0-9] using Javascript

This is what i want to do :

[image]

Any idea ?!?

Comment: what have you done until now?

Comment: No ideas. As you don't have any code to look into how anyone can suggest you anything? If possible for you post the code so that someone here can answer it properly.

Comment: The thing is i don't know how to start it (to be honest i don't even know how to search for it) i've hope that you can give me a good start i know that stackoverflow isn't a do your job site and i am sorry

Comment: So what is this table? A password creator (numbers only is very bad idea), or password validator (I can't imagine how this validates the password strength)? What do you really want to do?

Comment: @klenium it's a table that get only numbers to user to choose the input of his password and yes his password is only in number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get all the `td` and attach click event to it, then get the content of the `td` & append the `td` value to the value of the `input`

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll("#passwordTable td")].forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('pass').value += item.textContent.trim();

  })

})
```

```css
td {
  cursor: pointer
}

td:hover {
  background: blue;
  zoom: 1.1;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<input type='password' id='pass'>
<table border="2" id="passwordTable">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: it's a part of a solution i made it from scratch but i appreciate the effort thank you